# Trouble with rails g rspec:install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

The console gives me this:

```
/home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require': /home/action/aptmanage/config/application.rb:31: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)                                                                                                 
    from /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'                                         
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'                                                                                                                          
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at *config/application.rb* file, it probably has unbalanced do/end keywords.

Comment: I had it in the wrong spot in that file and there was a missing end. It's working now. Thanks for your help!